# CSS - box-sizing: border-box still adding border to overall height

Tags: css

I am attempting to place two buttons side by side, one of which has a border, and both of which are the same height. But even though I am using `box-sizing: border-box`, the border is still being added to the height.

Here are the links:

```css
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.15;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dib {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.btn {
  background-color: initial;
  text-align: initial;
  letter-spacing: initial;
  -webkit-transition: initial;
  transition: initial;
  -webkit-box-shadow: initial;
  box-shadow: initial;
  height: initial;
  border-radius: initial;
  vertical-align: initial;
  text-transform: initial;
}

.btn,
.btn-large,
.btn-small {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn,
.btn-large,
.btn-small,
.btn-flat {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.btn-ghost-secondary {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #261a94;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-ghost-secondary dib">Delete Entity</a>
<a class="btn btn-secondary dib">Edit Entity</a>
```

My understanding of `border-box` leads me to believe that the height of the `btn-ghost-secondary` button should be unaffected by the 2px border, and yet its height is exactly 4px more than that of its sibling.

I even tried removing all style other than display, padding, box-sizing and borders (you can see the difference in the buttons on the left hand side):

[image]
[image]

Comment: there is no border in your code and even if it's added it seems fine

Comment: Don't follow the problem. Both links have 36px in height, what's the issue?

Comment: Apologies, I missed one of the classes. Have added it back in. I'm not sure how to replicate the issue, I've literally removed everything in inspector except for borders, padding, inline-block, and box-sizing and yet for me the computed height of the ghost button is 40px.

Comment: your code is fine, check the dev tools

Comment: I'm completely baffled, I just went through and removed basically every bit of styling on the entire page other than the borders and box-sizing and the difference is still there.

Comment: I added some screenshots if it helps, you can see the difference in the buttons on the left hand side.

Comment: Are you sure the buttons have a `height` in your original code? They come out at 18px in the screenshot, which is the height of one line of text rather than the 36px expected from the snippet.

Comment: @MrLister the difference in the screenshot is that I've stripped out almost all of the other CSS on the whole page to eliminate the possibility that something else was interfering with it, that's why the size is slightly different than expected.

Comment: @DannySantos In that case, the screenshots don't demonstrate the problem. The one for the bordered button shows the calculated `height` property including the 2px border, which is as you want it. If you also disable `box-sizing`, the calculated `height` will change to 18px.

Comment: "The one for the bordered button shows the calculated height property including the 2px border, which is as you want it" - no that's not what I want, I want the border width to be included in the height. Which is what `border-box` should do, right? Disabling `box-sizing` has no effect, I just tried.

Comment: @DannySantos But the border size is included in the height. I don't know what else to say that hasn't been said before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186789/discussion-between-danny-santos-and-mr-lister).